# Using DataBuffer of BufferedImage to set pixels

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to use the underlying `DataBufferByte` of a `BufferedImage` of type `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` to set pixel values as quick as possible.

Perhaps I am not understanding, but when I do the following...

```
byte[] imgBytes = ((DataBufferByte) img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

... it seems as though I am getting a copy of the byte[] and not a reference. For example, if I run...

```
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(imgBytes));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode((DataBufferByte) img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData());
```

... I get two clearly different object hashes. If I'm not mistaken, this indicates that I am not getting a reference to the underlying byte[] but rather a copy. If this is the case, how am I supposed to edit the `DataBufferByte` directly???

Or perhaps I am just setting the pixels wrong... When I set pixels in the imgBytes it doesn't seem to do anything to the BufferedImage. Once I get the byte[], I set each pixel value like so:

```
imgBytes[intOffset] = byteBlue;
imgBytes[intOffset+1] = byteGreen;
imgBytes[intOffset+2] = byteRed;
```

To me, this all seems fine. I can read pixels just fine this way so it seems I should be able to write them the same way!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Hot-link to a small (in bytes) image or generate one in code.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You may not use getData() but use getRaster() which gives you an array you can use to write to.

Answer (score 1):

I once played around with pixel manipulations for Images in Java. Instead of directly answering your question I will offer an alternative solution to your problem. You can do the following to create an array of pixels to manipulate:

```
final int width = 800;
final int height = 600;
final int[] pixels = new int[width * height]; // 0xAARRGGBB
MemoryImageSource source = new MemoryImageSource(width, height, pixels, 0, width);
source.setAnimated(true);
source.setFullBufferUpdates(true);
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(source);
image.setAccelerationPriority(1f);
```

Then to draw the image, you can simply call the [drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) method from the Graphics class.

There are a few other ways to achieve what you are looking for, but this method was the simplest to me.

Comment: Interesting... I will have to test this out with an ImageTypeSpecifier & ColorModel in order to use it with a byte[] rather than int[] but this method seems promising.

I'm assuming this would be just as fast as editing the DataBuffer of a pre-existing BufferedImage, right?

Comment: As far as I know they would be roughly the same, but I haven't touched it in a long time, just thought I would offer a different solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it's implemented in JDK7. You may have an error somewhere else if the stuff doesn't work for you.

```
public byte[] getData() {
    theTrackable.setUntrackable();
    return data;
}
```